# Tracing database workloads of mobile applications under Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, database, profiling, workload

I want to understand the database workload (reads/writes against local database) of a mobile applications (third party, i.e. not developed by me) running under Android.

My options include:

1. Ask the developer of the application: Doubtful that this approach will work
2. Find scientific paper that has measured the DB workload of typical mobile applications. That would be perfect, but I've not found such a paper :-(
3. Profile a running application using an *emulator*, *profiler*, and/or a *trace-sensemaking* tool (e.g. detect transactions)

I need a solution for option 3, that is a tool for understanding the DB workload of a mobile application actively running under Android (iOS solution would also be ok)

I understand that this is hard. For starters, I can make no assumptions about the actual database that is being written to, although it is very likely to be SQLite.

I understand that the following might be part of the solution:

- Emulator, e.g. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html
- Tracing tools
- Trace sense-making tools

So, to summarize: **If you wanted to understand the DB workload of Angry Birds running under Android. How would you do this?**

Any information is useful, as I'm starting from scratch here :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a solution for the point **number 3** with Instruments in iOS (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: I will see if Instruments is useful to me, and upvote/accept answer accordingly :-) Thank you.

Comment: I've not had any luck yet tracing apps on the actual iphone device using Instruments, but it seems likely that I'll succeed in the near future. Only potential problem is that I'm running Snow Leopard, and can not upgrade xcode.